# On orthogonal complements of Hilbert Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

A well known theorem in the theory of Hilbert spaces is that if $H$ is our Hilbert space and $Y \subset H$ is closed, then $H = Y \oplus Y^{\perp}$.

Recently I started to feel like books treat this statement too literally. When we consider $Y$ (or $Y^{\perp}$ for that matter) we induce the topology of $X$ to $Y$. So is it really true that we have equality in this statement? I feel like we need to show that there isomorphism between the spaces.

Comment: It is a set theoretic identity.

Comment: And $Y\subset H$ is a closed *subspace*.

Answer (score 0):

The equality is fine, provided you understand the $\oplus$ as the "internal" direct sum, rather than the "external" direct sum. If you have vector spaces $U$ and $W$ of a vector space $V$, then $U \oplus W$ means two things: a set and a claim, specifically

1. the set $U + W = \{u + w : u \in U, w \in W\}$, and
2. for every $v \in U + W$, the $u \in U$ and $w \in W$ are unique.

As a set, $U \oplus W$ is (literally) equal to $U + W$, which is a literal subspace of $V$ (in the sense that every element of $U + W$ lies in $V$).

There's also the "external" direct sum, which also applies to vector spaces that aren't subspaces of the same space. Given vector spaces $U$ and $W$ over the same field, we can also define $U \oplus W$ to be $U \times W$ (in the sense of the Cartesian product),  and define addition and scalar multiplication sensibly from there. The elements of $U \oplus W$ are now ordered pairs $(u, v)$, and it is not the case that $U$ or $V$ are literally subspaces of $U \oplus W$.

If $U$ and $W$ are subspaces of $V$, and we consider the external direct sum, then certainly $U \oplus W$ is merely isomorphic to the subspace $U + W$ of $V$. But, typically, if the internal direct sum makes sense, we usually mean that over the external direct sum. This might be what's tripping you up.